# How to make neovim use the same colors as vim

Tags: neovim, st

I am trying to make neovim use the same coloring as vim.  Currently neovim is getting its colors from my 8 bright colors I have set in my ST configuration.  While vim uses the normal colors from my Simple Terminal configuration.  How do I make neovim use the normal colors instead of the bright colors?

The left side is what neovim currently looks like and the right is what vim currently looks like.
[image: Difference In colors.]

Simple Terminal Configuratin:

```
static const char *colorname[] = {
           /* 8 normal colors */
           "black",
           "red3",
           "green3",
           "yellow3",
           "blue2",
           "magenta3",
           "cyan3",
           "gray90",
 
          /* 8 bright colors */
          "gray50",
          "red",
          "green",
          "yellow",
          "#5c5cff",
          "magenta",
          "cyan",
          "white",
 
          [255] = 0,

          /* more colors can be added after 255 to use with DefaultXX */
         "#cccccc",
         "#555555",
        "black",
 };
```

Comment: [Probably related question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/8575/1841)

Answer (score 2):

I found out what the solution is.  vim was falsely assuming my background was light, while neovim found out that it was actually dark. Due to this neovim made all the colors brighter to compensate refer to https://neovim.io/doc/user/usr_06.html for more detail. So the solution is running the command:

```
set background=light
```

or put the command in the vimrc.